# ssl and chrome: err_ssl_protocol_error from time to time fixed with f5

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, tls1.2

We're having some issues on some machines related with ssl when connecting to our sites through https. sometimes, some of the users get the err_ssl_protocol_error when they try to load one of the sites. now, the weird thing is that hitting f5 solves the issue and the page that was returning the ssl error gets miraculous loaded. we've already tried most online suggestions (checking date and time, cleaning the browser/ssl cache, etc).

we have changed the ssl certificate recently (a month ago), but the issues have only started now. btw, all our requests go through our firewall (forti adc) which is responsible for enforcing the https to all our clients.

any clues on why we're getting this error?

**edit**: adding more info

- sites are hosted in iis (windows server 2016)
- our firewall is running forti adc
- the requests go through a load balancer before hitting firewall
- the firewall has the wildcard certificate used for ssl (all. sites)
- sites are built with aspnet
- it only happens on some pcs, and only with chrome (Firefox is working without any problems)

**edit 2**: More info from wireshark

So, I've used wireshark to capture the traffic and when I get the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on chrome, I've noticed that wireshark is showing me an alert with a decrypt error in response to the server hello message:

[image: Wireshark capture]

Any clues on what's going on here?

Comment: There is not enough information for us to answer your question. It could be a lot things causing this: proxy, vpn, your webserver or something completely different. Have you tried with a different browser? Could you give us more information? What's your webserver? What technologies do you use? Could you also tag it with something more meaningful, the web tag should not be used anyway.

Comment: I. know it's difficult to diagnose, but I'm running out of ideas. we've updated the certificates recently but since we've cleared the caches (chrome, ssl, etc) on the affected pcs, i really don't understand what's going on... especially why hitting f5 solves it and then after navigating over other pages, it happens again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of digging and testing, it seems like there's an issue with [openssl and ECDHE algorithms](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/8761). Changing the algorithm to a non ECDHE seems to have solved the issue for our chrome users...