Why does XHR Request randomly get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR?
We have a really old web application which uses JSP, plain JS and Java 8 running on JBOSS servers and ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR randomly occurs whenever application tries to get a resource or make an XHR post request. This error occurs randomly, one minute there is no problem with the request, immediately after that the same request gets the error. If this is a certificate or SSL problem, it would occur all the time. And i can't see the detail of the error, just ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERR. This application uses iframes. And CORS policy is set to same-origin. So there is no problem with that also. The status of XHR Request is 0 and statusText is empty. How can I get the detail of this error?
By the way we can't find any log of this request on the server or anywhere else, it is like it's blocked by the browser somehow. Users access this application from Chrome.
This is my XHR request code:
thisRequestObject.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
function processRequest() {
if (thisRequestObject.readyState == 4) {
    if (thisRequestObject.status == 200) {
        if (callbackFunction)
            callbackFunction(thisRequestObject);
    } else {
        alert("There was an error: (" + thisRequestObject.status + ") " + thisRequestObject.statusText);
    }
}

}
this.sendPostData = function()
{
    if (theURL)
    {
        thisRequestObject.open("POST", theURL, true);
        thisRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        thisRequestObject.send(sendString);
    }
};

When this error occurs, i don't see any response and response headers.
For example;



Sounds like a server error.  I suggest checking the jboss logs.

We checked but there is nothing there, we couldn't find any trace of it

If you check things like your general access log, that logs the HTTP requests that reached the server - then you can't expect to find it in there. Because that HTTP request was not made in the first place, since the client and server could not negotiate a proper secure connection to begin with. (What other kinds of logs JBOSS might have, I don't know.)

We also investigate the trace dump and there are no tls/ssl errors, if the problem were handshake, we would see it i guess

Serious long shot but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57857108/ssl-and-chrome-err-ssl-protocol-error-from-time-to-time-fixed-with-f5, The other thing is you need to enable a flag on JBoss to get the SSL errors and it changes all the damn time. See voted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563289/how-can-i-get-debug-messages-from-javas-ssl-handshake. Coincidentally, someone in comments identified ECDHE as issue there too.

Try updating OpenSSL and restarting everything after. If no, look into avoiding this cert type. Meanwhile, enable advanced logging -- its not necessarily true the request never made it to the server when its an SSL issue depending on server impl. Its being flags.

I activated the SSL debug logs but still i can't see anything wrong in the logs. Is it possible there is an incompatibility problem between iframes, jboss and chrome?
